# Caminho completo de arquivo em Python

Tags: python, arquivo, diretório

Estou utilizando o método `os.listdir()` para retornar uma lista de todos os arquivos, porém o retorno é apenas o nome do arquivo e eu gostaria que retornasse o caminho absoluto, alguém sabe alguma maneira ?

O método `os.path.abspath()` não está funcionando pois está me retornando a pasta do meu usuário + o arquivo sendo que o arquivo está dentro de subpastas do meu usuário.

Comment: Resolvi o meu problema utilizando a string que usei no método listdir() + o nome do arquivo, porém mesmo assim, seria bom saber qual o problema do método os.path.abspath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosto de utilizar o método `os.walk('caminho')`. O retorno é uma lista de tuplas. Onde cada tupla representa um caminho com seus respectivos diretórios e arquivos na forma de listas. O método percorre o diretório atual e seus subdiretórios.

```
import os
for caminho, diretorios, arquivos in os.walk():
    print caminho
    print diretorios
    print arquivos
```

Answer (score 2):

O método [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) retorna uma *lista* contendo os nomes dos arquivos e diretórios encontrados, o que pode estar acontecendo é que você deve estar utilizando o método [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) apontando para a lista devolvida de `os.listdir()` de modo errado, aplicando `os.path.abspath()` para cada item da lista deverá funcionar.

```
import os

dirlist = os.listdir(".") 
for i in dirlist:
    filename = os.path.abspath(i)
    print(filename)
```

A saída deve ser algo assim:

```
/home/user/dir1/dir2/arquivo1.py
/home/user/dir1/dir2/arquivo2.py
/home/user/dir1/dir2/foobarDir1
/home/user/dir1/dir2/foobarDir2
```

### Atualização

Como alternativa ao método [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) poderíamos estar fazendo algo como:

```
import os

filedirlist = os.listdir(".") 
filelist = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in filedirlist if os.path.isfile(f)]
dirlist  = [os.path.abspath(d) for d in filedirlist if os.path.isdir(d)]

# Lista de arquivos com path completo.
for i in filelist:
    print(i)

# Lista de diretórios com path completo.
for i in dirlist:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessantes para resolver esta questão é utilizando o seguinte código:

```
from os import chdir, listdir
from os.path import isfile

cam = input('Digite o caminho: ')

chdir(cam)

soma = 0
for c in listdir():
    if isfile(c):
        print(cam + '\\' + c)
        soma += 1
print()
print(f'{soma} arquivos encontrados.')
```

Observe que este código recebe o caminho de um diretório (pasta), a partir do qual será listado todos os arquivos junto com seus caminhos absolutos.

Answer (score 0):

costumo usar o `os.walk()`da seguinte forma:

```
from os import walk

for caminho,_,arquivo in walk('.'):
   print(str(caminho)+"/"+str(arquivo))
```